# Как закрепить фото?

Tags: telebot, photo

Вот таким способом фото не закрепляется, а сообщение закрепляется. Что делать?

```
photo_pin = bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption=args[1]) 
bot.pin_chat_message(chat_id = message.chat.id, message_id = photo_pin)
```